# PC monitor blink or turned off automatically when switch on the speaker

Tags: boot, display, power-supply, blank-screen

I have a 5 years old speaker connected to the same socket extension with my desktop PC (i.e. Monitor & PSU). When I turn my speaker on after the PC was booted up, sometimes the monitor will blink for a few seconds and return to operation.

However, there are a few ocassions in which my monitor won't show up. I can still hear my CPU fan running but I noticed that:-

- I couldn't toggle my Num/Caps Lock on my keyboard
- I turned the monitor off and on but it just showing Analog/Digital alternately and finally a blank screen

I've checked the connection is tight but still couldn't figure out the problem. This only happens when I have my PC running and turn on the speaker after that but not the other way round.

In addition, if I've experienced the blackout, sometimes I can't even boot up my PC properly. That is, I turn off everything and switch on my Monitor & PSU only and I can hear the boot up beep as usual but my monitor is showing Analog/Digital alternately again and then total blank. I've to use the hard power button on my PC to shut it down and repeat the boot up sequence a few times again to make it work.

This is very frustating and I'm not sure whether it's the failure of my speaker/PSU/monitor. Any help is appreciated!

## Hardware Specification

- Monitor (Samsung 2033)
- PSU (Gigabyte Hercules X 580)
- Speaker (SonicGear Ego 3nity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like your power supply is under-specked to handle the transient dip in power when you turn on your speaker,  and that your speaker is drawing an awful lot of power, very suddenly, on startup.

Doing a bit of research on that particular PSU, it appears that its performance is "[disappointing](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2181009/giagabyte-hercules-power-supply.html)", in line with its low price point, and this could be causing some of your issues.

Its possible that the issues with the monitor are similar in nature - if this is the case, you may want to move the speaker to a different socket, or, if that is not possible, put both your monitor and PC behind an ONLINE UPS, which will allow the UPS provide power during the transient brownout.

You will probably also find the power coming in to your property is not great.  Probably not a lot you can do about that though.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information @davidgo! Is it normal that the speaker behave in that way by pulling a lot of power? Can it happen for a faulty speaker? Does that mean the black-out was caused by the failure of PSU?

Comment: Without the equipment and tools we can only speculate.  I'm not an Audio expert but looking at the speaker specs I would not have expected   this behaviour - I did not realise the speaker was rated at 22 watts (which is not much)